# Accidentaly mixed 2 properties' data in Google analytics. Can i separate them backwards?

Tags: google-analytics

I just mashed up 2 Wordpress site's data by accidentally connecting the same GA property ID to both websites'(Monster Insights) Google Analytics plugin. This happened 2 days ago, so i have about 2 days worth of unwanted extra data from website "B" contaminated into my website "A" property's data. Now i found my fault and switched back to the proper ID now on. I would like to remove all unwanted extra data i collected from "B" in the past 2 days. Is there any solutions on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete the data already acquired in Analytics, but you can read the data cleanly by creating and applying a segment in Analytics in order to view only the data of a specific host name (thus excluding that of the unwanted site).